# Mysql query returning unknown column in java. Using intellij

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

The code:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smtp_program","root","xxxx");
    PreparedStatement stmt =
        con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM smtp_program.users WHERE username=?");
    stmt.setString(1,"'"+user+"'");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

variable user is being passed in as a String.

error its returning: [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'test1' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes:

```
stmt.setString(1, user);
```

the quotes are not needed as `executeUpdate()` will fix the statement correctly, by checking the type of the parameters and since you have used `setString()` the final statement will wrap `test1` inside single quotes:

```
DELETE FROM smtp_program.users WHERE username='test1'
```

Your code passes `'test1'` to `setString()` and this results to:

```
DELETE FROM smtp_program.users WHERE username='''test1'''
```

because `executeUpdate()` **escapes** the single quotes by adding 2 more at the start and at the end and this is interpreted as the column name/alias `'test1'` instead of a string literal.